# Using https proxy with aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, python-asyncio, pytest-aiohttp

I need to fetch data from an https url. I've learned that aiohttp doesn't support https proxy. Is there a way to overcome this. I've read lots of previous replies but couldn't find anything.

```
async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url, proxy=proxies['https']) as response:
        res_dic = await response.json()
        status = response.status

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
with ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
    loop.run_until_complete(*[asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url, session)) for url in urls])
loop.close()
```

I have my proxies like this

```
proxies = {
    "https": "https://{}:{}@{}".format(username, password, proxy_url),
    "http": "http://{}:{}@{}".format(username, password, proxy_url)
}
```

Comment: This may or may not help: httpx supports https proxies. See https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#http-proxying

Comment: `with httpx.Client(headers=headers, 
proxies=proxies) as client:`
 `resp = client.get(url)`
 `print(resp.json())`

@dim
I tried this and i get the error

`httpx.ConnectError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)`